# Particle fields and field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, universe, unified-theories

All particles have their own fields. More precisely, I've learned that an electron is just a bundle-up packet of energy from an 'electron field'. So as in this sense, all particles (from the standard model) have their own respective fields. Quark from it's quark field,  electron from it's electron field, and so on.

My question is that, can all these fields be unified to a single field? I'm not talking about gravity and the unification of gravity with the fields. I'm asking whether such a field is possible which is the sum total of all the fields and which *birthed* the different fields that we see in our universe?

Comment: A proton is not an elementary particle in the Standard Model

Comment: Omg yeah my mistake

Answer (score 2):

What you are envisaging is called a [unified field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_field_theory) or [Grand Unified Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory). It is an area of active research in particle physics. A Nobel prize almost certainly awaits anyone who can come up with such a theory along with experimental evidence that verifies it.

Answer (score 1):

The Electromagnetic force and the Weak force have been shown experimentally to unify in the Electroweak force. We have many GUTs (Grand Unified Theories) that also unite the Electroweak and Strong force, but sadly we have no experimental evidence of that.

Comment: GUTs uses supersymmetry, right?

Comment: Not exactely, they might appeal some theory because of symmetry breaking giving birth to strong force and electroweak, but not all GUTs use supersymmetry. Boson string theory for example does not use it

Comment: Has bosonic string theory ever even been a serious contender for the GUT?